# How do I find number of overlapping months between a set of dates and ANY June - Nov period of any year?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The formula we used is =COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(MONTH(SEQUENCE(P60-P59,,P59)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(SEQUENCE(P60-P59,,P59),SEQUENCE(E81-E80,,E80),0)),""))))

It works flawlessly but I need it to work now for comparing a set of dates such as 2/1/2021 - 10/1/2021 and ANY June-November period of ANY year. In the formula used right now, it doesn't work for finding overlapping months in 2/1/2022 - 7/1/2022 since 2/1/2022 - 7/1/2022 doesn't overlap with 6/1/2021 - 11/30/2021. Can I find the number of matching months between any set of dates and any 6/1/## - 11/30/## period of any year?

Answer (score 0):

Use MONTH to only look at Months:

```
=COUNT(FILTER(UNIQUE(MONTH(SEQUENCE(P60-P59,,P59))),ISNUMBER(MATCH(UNIQUE(MONTH(SEQUENCE(P60-P59,,P59))),UNIQUE(MONTH(SEQUENCE(E81-E80,,E80))),0)),""))
```

now only the months will be looked at and not the year.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :/ I copied the formula you typed and it says "too many arguments". Then after correcting that it just returns the same as before. I need it to just tell me the number of months from June to Nov that overlap with any set of two dates.

Comment: @Bryan see edit.  I had the `)` in the wrong places.

Comment: I still get the same result. It basically only counts the months overlapping in 2021 but ignores the ones in 2022. I am using the range 2/1/2021 - 8/1/2022 and I need to know how many months June - Nov are in that range. The answer should be 8 because there are 6 overlapping in 2021 and 2 more in 2022. If you can help me figure this one out you will be a God and savior.

Comment: @Bryan I have wracked my Brain on this and have not come up with an easy method to do what you want.  I will keep chewing on it.

Comment: Thank you thank you! I will keep trying too.